# Converting a Java Timestamp into a String?

Tags: java, json, string, calendar, timestamp

I have the following field in my Java Entity:

```
@JsonProperty
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "start_date")
private Calendar startDate;
```

It is currently a `timestamp` when we send it to the front end via `json`.

How can I convert this into a `string` to send to front end?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime`from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). If using Jackson, you will need [Set of support modules for Java 8 datatypes](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@JsonSerialize` annotation.

```
@JsonProperty
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "start_date")
@JsonSerialize(using = CalenderSerializer.class)
private Calendar startDate;
```

Serializer:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

public class CalenderSerializer extends StdSerializer<Calendar> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 72941023713498596L;
    private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

    public CalenderSerializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    public CalenderSerializer(Class<Calendar> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Calendar value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString(sdf.format(value.getTime()));
    }
}
```